# Partial Pivoting/Gaussian elimination- swapping columns instead of rows producing wrong output

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a quick program to solve a system of linear equations. The program reads the input from a file and then writes the upper-triangular system and solutions to a file. It is working with no pivoting, but when I try to implement the pivoting it produces incorrect results.
As example input, here is the following system of equations:

```
w+2x-3y+4z=12
2w+2x-2y+3z=10
x+y=-1
w-x+y-2z=-4
```

I expect the results to be w=1, x=0, y=-1 and z=2. When I don't pivot, I get this answer (with some rounding error on x). When I add in the pivoting, I get the same numbers but in the wrong order: w=2,x=1,y=-1 and z=0.

What do I need to do to get these in the correct order? Am I missing a step somewhere? I need to do column swapping instead of rows because I need to adapt this to a parallel algorithm later that requires that. Here is the code that does the elimination and back substitution:

```
void gaussian_elimination(double** A, double* b, double* x, int n)
{
    int maxIndex;
    double temp;
    int i;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {               
        i = k;
        for (int j = k+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (abs(A[k][j]) > abs(A[k][i]))
            {
                i = j;
            }
        }       

        if (i != k)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                temp = A[j][k];
                A[j][k] = A[j][i];
                A[j][i] = temp;
            }           
        }


        for (int j = k + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            A[k][j] = A[k][j] / A[k][k];
        }
        b[k] = b[k] / A[k][k];
        A[k][k] = 1;
        for (i = k + 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = k + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                A[i][j] = A[i][j] - A[i][k] * A[k][j];
            }
            b[i] = b[i] - A[i][k] * b[k];
            A[i][k] = 0;
        }
    }

}

void back_substitution(double**U, double*x, double*y, int n)
{
    for (int k = n - 1; k >= 0; k--)
    {
        x[k] = y[k];
        for (int i = k - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            y[i] = y[i] - x[k]*U[i][k];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the remainder of your code to make it a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you implemented is actually complete pivoting.

With complete pivoting, you must keep track of the permutation of columns, and apply the same permutation to your answer.

You can do this with an array {0, 1, ..., n}, where you swap the i'th and k'th values in the second loop. Then, rearange the solution using this array.

If what you were trying to do is partial pivoting, you need to look for the maximum in the respective row, and swap the rows and the values of 'b' accordingly.